# Pyramid pattern in php

Tags: php

I have pattern like this.

```
    * 
    * * 
    * * * 
    * * * * 
    * * * * *
```

my code is as follows

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++){
        echo "  ";
    }
    for($m=1;$m<=$i;$m++){
        echo "*  ";
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
```

but I want pattern like the following one. I have tried but could not get it.

```
* 
* * *
* * * * *
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: no.. it is not possible.. with this i cant get first rows single star..

Comment: Why not? Can you tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simply using `str_repeat` and `$i += 2` instead of `$i++`

```
for($i = 1;$i < 10; $i+=2){
    echo str_repeat('* ',$i)."<br>";
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/403028)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. working fine

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i+=2){
for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
echo "*&nbsp;";
}
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively from Uchida i notice that you want to have 5 rows where first row has the 1st odd number of * (1 is the first odd number) and the last row has the 5th odd number of * (9 nine is the 5th odd number).

You can achieve that by applying that logic into code:

```
 for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++) {   // Here we define the amount of rows notice we start from '0'
    for($m=1;$m<=(2*$i+1);$m++) { // Here we compute the right odd number
       echo "*  ";
    }
    echo "</br>";       
 }
```